# PHP - readable date from negative long timestamp with custom base year

Tags: php, date, timestamp, jet

I've seen a number of questions and answers on StackOverflow covering the scenario where timestamps have been based on the Unix Epoch but have been struggling to combine the solutions and modify them into a working solution for the data and custom base year I've been supplied.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London' );

function TransformDate( $iTimeStamp ) {
  /* Insert transform code here */
  $dt = new DateTime( '@' . $iTimeStamp );
  return $dt->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
}

/* These timestamps should be between Sep-2014 and Jan-2015 */
$aTest = array( '-1554460973', '-1554427073', '-1554142396', '-1554139421' );
foreach( $aTest as $i ) echo( $i . ' - ' . TransformDate( $i ) . "\r\n" );
```

The only information I have to help process these timestamps is that they are based on the year `2013`, with `10` ticks per second, and the data was originally from a Microsoft Jet database (so I would imagine similar data storage types to Microsoft Access etc).

I have tried so many combinations of adding or substracting the *strtotime* result value of `2013-01-01` and `1899-12-30`, and multiplying and dividing by `10` that I've simplylost track now. For example:

```
$iTimeStamp -= strtotime( '2013-01-01' );
$iTimeStamp += strtotime( '1899-12-30' );
$iTimeStamp = round( $iTimeStamp / 10 );
```

So far though the closest I've got though is dates in 2012, though the December 31st 14:38pm part of the the date could be right:

```
$iTimeSinceBase = ( $iTimeStamp - strtotime( '2013-01-01' )) / 86400;
$iTimeStamp = strtotime( '2013-01-01' ) + $iTimeSinceBase;
```

The output for which is:

```
-1554460973 = 2012-12-31 14:38:22
-1554427073 = 2012-12-31 14:38:22
-1554142396 = 2012-12-31 14:38:26
-1554139421 = 2012-12-31 14:38:26
```

At this point any assistance is welcome! Thank you.

Comment: Your output is invalid, it should be year 1920, see [demo](https://eval.in/247786). Your function `TransformDate` returns formated datetime in UTC timezone or `+00:00` offset, you should keep that in mind.

Comment: You need to add the two lines above my output into the script where I put the comment "Insert Transform Code Here" in order to get the 2012 dates. Thanks for the headsup on the UTC-0 offset.

Comment: Sorry, but I am lost what you need... What kind of output you wish to get from input `-1554460973` ?

Comment: Interestingly pastebin gives back some very different dates with the transform code added - `5578-12-31`, `9502-01-01`, `2013-01-01`, `2794-12-31` using PHP 5.5.14. I'm currently running 5.3.4.dev to get the ouput I posted. I'm not sure I understand why different PHP version should affect this.

Comment: I'm looking for output similar to that I posted except that the dates must be between Sep-2014 and Jan-2015 otherwise the calculation method is wrong. Thats the period of data I've taken these values from that need converting to human readable dates and times.